# How does Reddit load recently loaded pages so quickly?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, reddit

I understand that Reddit uses AJAX, but I'm confused as to how it opens previously-opened pages so quickly. For example, if I open r/popular, then go to r/worldnews, if I navigate back to r/popular (by clicking a link) then it loads r/popular without sending requests to the server. However, if I refresh the page, all data for previously-viewed pages disappears, and requests have to be sent to the server to get the data to display those pages.

It doesn't seem that anything is being stored in the browser cache or cookies. I do notice, though, that when a new page is opened, a folder is created in the Chrome DevTools Sources tab, under reddit.com origin. Any ideas? Understanding this is key to being able to finish my Google Chrome extension.

Comment: AJAX site means it uses HTML5 [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) so the data is inside JS objects. There are many frameworks and libraries that allow to implement a so-called Single-Page-Application paradigm. It's a huge topic so google it up, there are lots of tutorials.

Comment: Can't be sure, it'd require looking at the code, but it's a SPA, I'd *bet* they just save a reference to the subreddit page element (or the HTML). There are no network requests nor any websocket connections, so they must be just re-displaying what was shown to you earlier.